# Google PubSub Subscription Name for multiple VMs?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

I would like to create a managed Compute Engine group, with some startup scripts, including one that creates a subscription to an Object Change Notification. Following [these tutorials](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull), these subscriptions all require a "subscription_name".

I can't set it to a static name since it'll cause clashes when >1 VMs are spun up.

Is there a way to automatically 'increment' the name, i.e. 'VM_sub_1', 'VM_sub_2', 'VM_sub_3'... etc.?

Or is leaving it blank and accepting randomly-generated names the only way to avoid clashes?

Code sample for creating subscription:

```
def create_push_subscription(project_id, topic_name, subscription_name, endpoint):
"""Create a new push subscription on the given topic."""
# [START pubsub_create_push_subscription]
from google.cloud
import pubsub_v1
project_id = "bucketcfpubsub"
topic_name = "bucketcfpubsub"
subscription_name = "VM_sub_1"
endpoint = "https://bucketcfpubsub.appspot.com/push"
subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
topic_path = subscriber.topic_path(project_id, topic_name)
subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(project_id, subscription_name)

push_config = pubsub_v1.types.PushConfig(push_endpoint = endpoint)
subscription = subscriber.create_subscription(subscription_path, topic_path, push_config)
print('Push subscription created: {}'.format(subscription))
print('Endpoint for subscription is: {}'.format(endpoint))#[END pubsub_create_push_subscription]
```

Attempt at fetching metadata:

```
def check_instance():
    import time
    import requests

    METADATA_URL = 'http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/id'
    METADATA_HEADERS = {'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'}

    instance_id = requests.get(METADATA_URL, headers=METADATA_HEADERS)

    print(instance_id)

check_instance()
```

returns

> Response [200]

meanning

> Success! A value was changed, or you reached your specified timeout_sec and the request returned successfully.

Comment: Can you please include the code you are using?

Comment: Why not just use the instance-id as the subscription name? The only thing that really matters is the Pub/Sub Topic.

Comment: Using the instance-id will also make it easier to delete the subscription on instance termination.

Comment: Added the code I was going to use. How do I use instance-id as the name? subscription_name = instanceId?

Comment: To get the instance ID, read the instance metadata from the HTTP endpoint inside the instance: `http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/id`. You can use the Python `requests` package to do this. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata#project_and_instance_metadata

Comment: I've attempted some basic python to do that, as pasted [here](https://pastebin.com/kLVVxsFP), but it returns <Response [200]>. What am I doing wrong?